# Returning a value of an unsigned char array throws a SIGABRT error

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in c++ and I am trying to write a program to read the cpu temperature of a Mac.

I am reading the cpu temperature as an array of bytes and the temperature is then the first value in this array. However when I am trying to return this first value of the array I get an SIGABRT error.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

This is my code:

```cpp
void SMCKit::readKey(smc_key_t smcKey, SMCBytes &result) {
    SMCParamStruct inputStruct = SMCParamStruct();

    inputStruct.key = smcKey.code;
    inputStruct.keyInfo.dataSize = (UInt32) smcKey.info.size;
    inputStruct.data8 = kSMCReadKey;

    SMCParamStruct resultStruct = callSMC(inputStruct);
    std::copy(std::begin(resultStruct.bytes), std::end(result), std::begin(result));
}

unsigned char SMCKit::readCPUTemp() {
    SMCKey key = SMCKey("TC0F", types.SP78);
    unsigned char readResult[32];
    readKey(key, readResult);

    return readResult[0]; // -> the error occurs here
}
```

Using the debugger I found out that the code runs perfectly fine (and readResult has the expected result) till the last line. In the line where the read result is returned.

Comment: You have a bug in the line where `std::copy` is invoked. First two params of `copy` define input range. Second param should be `std::end(resultStruct.bytes)`.

Comment: @rafix07 That's pretty much an answer ...

Comment: @rafix07 That was the problem. Thank you very much! :)